# typecast/transform each element of list of lists to appropriate type

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I am looking for a way to typecast or transform each element of this list of lists, to the appropriate type.

The list needs to be inserted in a SQL database, so every first element of the list of lists might be typecasted to a `str`, the second to a `str`, the third to a `float` etc. (depending on the type of the column)

```
[["myfirstcolumn", "second", "3", "False", "20200102"],
 ["myfirstcolumn", "second", "2", "True", "20200101"],
 ["myfirstcolumn", "second", "1", "False", "20200104"],
 ["myfirstcolumn", "second", "5", "True", "20200106"],
 ["myfirstcolumn", "second", "6", "True", "20200107"],
 ["myfirstcolumn", "second", "7", "True", "20200108"]...]
```

I already looped over every element and typecasted each individually, but that takes time if you have like 2.000.000 items. Is there a way to just transform all items based on their position in each list?

So my idea: transform every first element of each list to a `str` at once, every second to a `str`, every third to a `float` etc.

I thought of numpy, but numpy wants every subarray to be a single type. Or is there a way to rotate the numpy array so each subarray becomes a column, transform them, and rotate them back (and transform them back to a list of lists or list of tuples) before insertion to the database???

Comment: you want a [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think you could get it to work faster if you use Pandas:

```py
arr = [["myfirstcolumn", "second", "3", "False", "20200102"],
       ["myfirstcolumn", "second", "2", "True", "20200101"],
       ["myfirstcolumn", "second", "1", "False", "20200104"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df[2] = df[2].astype("float")
df[3] = df[3].astype("bool")
df[4] = df[4].astype("int")

values = df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: Note that duplicates are removed (which is probably not a problem but a feature)

Comment: That does make things much easier. Do you have an idea as well for values which are empty? Like if a column with boolean values as strings, if a cell contains an empty string, I cannot cast them to "bool" without an error. Any thoughts how to handle does? Ideally I want them to become "None".

Comment: To replace all empty strings with None, you can use replace: `df.replace("", None, regex=True)`